# Bound on the total variation distance for multiple samples $d_{tv}(P^n,Q^n)$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Given two discrete distributions $P$ and $Q$, with computable total variation distance $d_{TV}(P,Q)=||P - Q||_1$, is there a precise bound for $d_{TV}(P^n,Q^n)=||P^n - Q^n||_1$, as need to estimate the power of an optimal test for multiple samples? Moreover, is is possible to exactly compute $d_{TV}(P^n,Q^n)=||P^n - Q^n||_1$ without enumerating all combinations?

The best bound that I could find is based on the Chernoff Information [The complexity of distinguishing distributions](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/126225/files/BV08.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact formula for computing $d_{TV}(P^n,Q^n)$ in terms of
$d_{TV}(P,Q)$ alone. Consider the example
$P=(0,1)$, $Q=(0.1,0.9)$, $P'=(0.2,0.8)$. Then $d_{TV}(P,Q)=d_{TV}(P',Q)=0.2$, but
$$ 0.38 = d_{TV}(P^2,Q^2) \neq d_{TV}({P'}^2,Q^2) = 0.34 .$$
For an upper bound, you can use Pinsker's inequality:
$$ d_{TV}(P^n,Q^n)^2/2 \le n \min(KL(P||Q),KL(Q||P), $$
where KL is the Kullback-Leibler divergence, which is defined in your linked article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Are there any other known upper bounds that I could look into, as the KL distance is not always defined...

Comment: I would say KL is always defined, just not always finite.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer correct if you agree with it :)